# Using Index to return max of lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any help here would be greatly received.
I have a list of locations and a list of faults as thus:

```
Controller   Error
A            1
B            1
A            2
A            2
B            3
```

This is for many thousands of faults, what I need is a formula to return the name of the most occurring error for a given controller using excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that table in `A1:B6` (with headers in row 1) and your choice of Controller, e.g. "B", in `C1`, **array formula****:

`=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MODE(IF(A$2:A$6=C1,MATCH(B$2:B$6,B$2:B$6,{0,0}))))`

If, for the chosen Controller, no one Error is more frequent than any other, then, of those Errors sharing the highest frequency, that which occurs earliest in the list will be returned.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works perfectly. Could i press you for an addition? Can the same be used to get the count of the fault as well in a separate cell?

Comment: Sure. But what do you mean by the "count of the fault"?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=MODE(IF(A2:A6="A";B2:B6))
```

as an array formula (press Strg+Enter instead of Enter). Instead of "A" you can use a reference to a cell containing the controller you want to select.
Be aware that in your minimal example this formula doesn't work for controller B because MODE apparently needs at least three values.